# NestJs @Sse - event is consumed only by one client

Tags: nestjs, server-sent-events

I tried the sample SSE application provided with nest.js ([28-SSE](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/28-sse)), and modified the sse endpoint to send a counter:

```
  @Sse('sse')
  sse(): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    return interval(5000).pipe(
      map((_) => ({ data: { hello: `world - ${this.c++}` }} as MessageEvent)),
    );
  }
```

I expect that **each** client that is listening to this SSE will receive the message, but when opening multiple browser tabs I can see that each message is consumed only by one browser, so if I have three browsers open I get the following:

[image]

How can I get the expected behavior?

Comment: Are the same browser(profile) tabs in your screenshot?

Comment: Same behavior even in two different browsers (chrome / edge).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve the behavior you're expecting you need to create a separate stream for each connection and push the data stream as you wish.

One possible minimalistic solution is below

```js
import { Controller, Get, MessageEvent, OnModuleDestroy, OnModuleInit, Res, Sse } from '@nestjs/common';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Controller()
export class AppController implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  private stream: {
    id: string;
    subject: ReplaySubject<unknown>;
    observer: Observable<unknown>;
  }[] = [];
  private timer: NodeJS.Timeout;
  private id = 0;

  public onModuleInit(): void {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.id += 1;
      this.stream.forEach(({ subject }) => subject.next(this.id));
    }, 1000);
  }

  public onModuleDestroy(): void {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  @Get()
  public index(): string {
    return readFileSync(join(__dirname, 'index.html'), 'utf-8').toString();
  }

  @Sse('sse')
  public sse(@Res() response: Response): Observable<MessageEvent> {
    const id = AppController.genStreamId();
    // Clean up the stream when the client disconnects
    response.on('close', () => this.removeStream(id));
    // Create a new stream
    const subject = new ReplaySubject();
    const observer = subject.asObservable();
    this.addStream(subject, observer, id);

    return observer.pipe(map((data) => ({
      id: `my-stream-id:${id}`,
      data: `Hello world ${data}`,
      event: 'my-event-name',
    }) as MessageEvent));
  }

  private addStream(subject: ReplaySubject<unknown>, observer: Observable<unknown>, id: string): void {
    this.stream.push({
      id,
      subject,
      observer,
    });
  }

  private removeStream(id: string): void {
    this.stream = this.stream.filter(stream => stream.id !== id);
  }

  private static genStreamId(): string {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
  }
}
```

You can make a separate service for it and make it cleaner and push stream data from different places but as an example showcase this would result as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Why is it important to use reply subject in that case ?

Comment: The only requirement for SSE to work in NestJS is to return an Observable stream. Technically you can return `new Observable(...)` with the static data in it but in a real-world scenario, you do not wish to return static data, it would be dynamic. When you want to inject data into the stream you can use `Subject` or `ReplaySubject` they are almost the same. The thing is that with Subject/ReplaySubject you can return it as an observable and push data into the stream with `next` method while in `new Observable()` you can't. _(at least that's how I know it)_

Answer (score 3):

you just have to generate a new observable for each sse connection of the same subject

```
 private events: Subject<MessageEvent> = new Subject();

 constuctor(){
   timer(0, 1000).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(async (index: any)=>{
            let event: MessageEvent = { 
                id: index, 
                type: 'test', 
                retry: 30000, 
                data: {index: index}
            } as MessageEvent;
            this.events.next(event);
   });
 }

 @Sse('sse')
 public sse(): Observable<MessageEvent> {
   return this.events.asObservable();
 }
```

Note: I'm skipping the rest of the controller code.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is correct. Each SSE connection is a dedicated socket and handled by a dedicated server process. So each client can receive different data.
It is not a broadcast-same-thing-to-many technology.

> How can I get the expected behavior?

Have a central record (e.g. in an SQL DB) of the desired value you want to send out to all the connected clients.

Then have each of the SSE server processes watch or poll that central record
and send out an event each time it changes.

Comment: "This behaviour is correct. Each SSE connection is a dedicated socket and handled by a dedicated server process. So each client can receive different data. It is not a broadcast-same-thing-to-many technology."

Doesn't it contradict the SSE concept of one-to-many broadcasting ?

Comment: @sharon.biren SSE is not a one-to-many broadcast technology. (Neither are websockets.)  If you've seen it described like that somewhere you were looking at an unreliable reference.

Comment: So actually if there are multiple clients who are registered to the same SSE endpoint (in NestJS) , then when the server returns a message event it will get just to one client ?

Comment: @sharon.biren Each client to the SSE endpoint is a dedicated socket, and the server can send a different message to each client, and at different times. However a server could maintain a list of all those connections, and loop through them and send each the same message. So you can build a broadcast-same-thing-to-many technology _on top of_ SSE.

Comment: that's weird, because when i'm emitting some event , the 2 Chrome tabs that subscribed to this endpoint gets the same message. without maintaining a list of all clients connections.
I'm using EventEmitter in NestJS